# Jquery if empty loop in live preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm having a working live preview Script. But now i want that the field for phone and fax only are displayed, when there is an input in the form fields. But i guess there has to be an issue with the empty statement. Does anyone has an idea to fix this? Thank you very much!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  updatePreview();

  $('#live-preview-form input, #live-preview-form textarea #live-preview-form select').bind('blur keyup',updatePreview);
});

function updatePreview(){
  var   contact             = $('#lp-contact'),
        company_name    = $('#lp-company_name'),
        company_extra   = $('#lp-company_extra'),
        adress          = $('#lp-adress'),
        country_code    = $('#lp-country_code'),        
        zip                 = $('#lp-zip'),     
        city            = $('#lp-city'),        
        phone           = $('#lp-phone'),
        fax                 = $('#lp-fax'),
        url                 = $('#lp-url'),
        mail            = $('#lp-mail');


        contact.text($('#contact').val());
        company_name.text($('#company_name').val());
        company_name.html($('#lp-company_name').html().replace(/\n/g,'<br />'));
        company_extra.text($('#company_extra').val());
        adress.text($('#adress').val());
        country_code.text($('#country_code').val() + '-' );
        zip.text($('#zip').val());
        city.text($('#city').val());
        if(! $('#phone')){phone.text('T ' + $('#phone').val())};
        if(! $('#fax')){fax.text('F ' + $('#fax').val())};
        url.text($('#url').val());
        mail.text($('#mail').val());
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8j4ykkgu/)

[JS Fiddle Update #1](http://jsfiddle.net/8j4ykkgu/1/)

After a lot of trying and research i thought, maybe it works with this code: but it didn't.

```
 if (phone.text($('#phone').val().length) != 0){
        phone.text('T ' + $('#phone').val());
    };
```

Comment: Please post a fiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This conditions:

```
if (!$('#phone')) {
    phone.text('T ' + $('#phone').val())
};
```

should be

```
if (!$('#phone').length) {
    phone.text('T ' + $('#phone').val())
};
```

The thing is that `$('#phone')` is a jQuery instance object which is always a truthy value. This object is an [array-like collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like) of the HTML elements. So correct way to check if the element is on page is to check the length of this collection. Basically, it can be demonstrated with this simple snippet:

```js
if ({length: 0}) {
    alert('One');
}

if ({length: 0}.length) {
    alert('Two');
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and your very good explanation. Badly it doesn't work in my script. I updated the fiddle with your 2. code snippet. Nothing changend. Any idea?

Comment: No, but maybe i'm the problem with describing my problem :-) The Letters F and T should only are visible, when there is an input in the fields.

Comment: I'm still trying. I edit another idea, but didn't work out. You can see the edit in the question.

Comment: okay, I got what you want to achieve. Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8j4ykkgu/3/

Comment: this is exactly, was i'm was looking for. Cool. Thank you very much! May you help me to explain how it works?

Comment: Sure. `$('#phone').val().trim().length` is the length of the string entered in the `#phone` field. Double negation `!!` acts as a boolean conversion. So if the length of the value is `0` then `!!0` => `false`. Otherwise it's `true`. Then [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method shows `phone` if `showPhone` is true, and hides if `false` is passed into it. After that since toggle returns the same `phone` jQuery object so you can set its text with `text` method.